# Do Raphael elements like RECT support the zIndex attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Raphael elements do not seem to respond to zIndex modifications for me.  I've tried everything to reorder  a bunch of rectangles drawn one over the other and they remain unchanged.  Here is what I tried.

```
$(".c10").css({zIndex: 0});
$(".c50").css({zIndex: 0});
$(".c90").css({zIndex: 0});
```

I thought that this would send all the c90s to the bottom of the stack, visually.

Any thoughts?

Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

The zIndex does not seem to work.  The only way I got this to work is by iterating through the elements and using the following to push back the elements class by class below one another.

```
    for (var j=0; j < lnt; j++) {
    jj = "c"+j*10;
    for (var i=0; i <lnt; i++) {
        z = window[dots[i]];
        if (z.class == jj){
            z.toBack();
        }
    }
}
```

The essence of the idea is to get at the raphael element and use the plain old toBack() function.